# Getent group with a long name and multiple spaces - SSSD

Tags: linux, redhat, sssd

So I'm trying to return a group but I think the string is either to long or it's just not compatible with SSSD.

So backgroup is I've already tested this domain for a user and also a group e.g

```
getent passwd user1@domain2
```

and I get a return.

I also get the group name i'm looking for when i do

```
groups user1@domain2
```

Now I need to do a getent group with this group name and it looks like this:

```
group group1 group2 basic administrator
```

Yes it's the name of just one group, and yes it has all these spaces.

So I've tried:

```
getent groups 'group group1 group2 basic administrator@domain2'

getent groups "group group1 group2 basic administrator@domain2"
```

Any other way I can do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The getent I'm using on RHEL7 is using syntax of "group" not "groups" and it works just placing quotes around it all for me:

```
getent group "DOMAIN\\group name with spaces"
```